# attacked by a virus on my system. keyboard not working properly

Tags: malware, virus

3 days back i was attacked by a virus and my system is behaving badly. i have all the latest antivirus but even after virus were quarantined some of the problems i am facing are.

- on startup the system loops and doesn't let me login with username and password.
- caps lock, ctrl, num lock, numbers 8,9,4 and some keys like v, f are not working,also @ is not working.
- the browser is now showing a green border on its circumference.

backspace not working. i have to take support of virtual keyboard.

kindly suggest something. i have already brought a new laptop 4 years ago and this has happened again.

Comment: That doesn't sound like the work of a virus, it sounds like it's busted to me. What makes you think it was malware?

Comment: Go to a presume clean system and download any rescue disk from prominent Antivirus vendor and create a bootable image on the pendrive/thumbdrive. Boot from there and make a scanning.  Since some malware might overwrite some common notebook software, you might need to make a restore.  Also prepare a backup, you might need to initiate a full system reinstall (using the laptop recovery features).

Comment: Are you using [QuickHeal antivirus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A8uSiB1DdFE)? How do you know about the keyboard and browser problems without being able to log in?

Comment: yes i am using quickheal

Answer (score 0):

I would take those steps:

1)Login on safe-mode.

2)Scan computer with "Malwarebytes".

3)Try Scan with other Anti-viruses.

If neither of that won't work try backing-up your drives and format your computer...